# Assign namespace in freemarker from string

Tags: java, import, freemarker

Is there any possible way to assign a namespace from a string in FreeMarker? I have also tried to evaluate it but that won't work either.

```
<#assign myFruit = ["bannana","apple","orange","pear"]>

<#list myFruit as i>
  <#assign fruitTemplate="path/to/${i}.ftl" fruitNamespace="ns${i?capitalize}" />
  <#import "${fruitTemplate}" as ${fruitNamespace} /> 
</#list>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment targets (like that after `as`) are syntactically non-expressions, just identifiers. However, you can work that around with `?interpret`, which parses an arbitrary string value (that can come from any expression) to an object that you can call like a macro. In your case:

```
<@'<#import fruitTemplate as ${fruitNamespace}>'?interpret />
```

`?eval` doesn't work because it parses FTL *expressions*, not FTL.

Comment: Cool. Can you document this workaround in `import`/`assign` docs? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Sure, I have added this to the 2.3.22 Manual.